# command not found: tensorflowjs_converter

Tags: pip, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I'm trying to convert a frozen model graph file (.pb file) to tensorflowjs model file using tensorflowjs-convertor. 
As mentioned in their documentation , I've installed tensorflowjs package with below command :

```
pip install tensorflowjs
```

While running the command to convert , it throws this error :

```
zsh: command not found: tensorflowjs_converter
```

Looks like that command is still not available after installing the package. I couldn't find any useful workaround regarding this. Can anyone help fixing this please ?

Comment: How do you start your cmd/powershell?

Comment: This is on Mac. I use iTerm.

Comment: Are there any errors after/during the installation of `tensorflowjs` and when you want to run `tensorflowjs_converter` does `pip` still work, because it could be problem with the python environment

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel There was one error while installing tensorflowjs, that was causing the issue. I've fixed it and I'm able to run the command now. Thanks :)

Comment: Should I add my comment as an answer?

Comment: What was the solution? I cannot get this working.

Comment: @clement360 My issue was with the pip install. What issue are you facing ?

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel Yes you can.

Comment: Doesn't work on Windows either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `pip install tensorflowjs` completes successfully, before trying to use `tensorflowjs_converter`.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work on Ubuntu either (Tensorflow 2.0.0, Dec. 2019). Running pip with sudo doesn't help.